# What is this leg accessory that Noelle wears?

Tags: black-clover

In *Black Clover: Quartet Knight*, Noelle wears an accessory on her legs.

[image: Image of Noelle]

What is that clothing thing on her legs called?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't those just called [leg warmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leg_warmer)? Other characters like Hinamori Amu (Shugo Chara), Kagamine Rin and Len (Vocaloid), and Rock Lee (Naruto) are known to wear them.

Answer (score 1):

In her case, they are Genie Leg warmers.

Not just leg warmers, because they are made of a lightweight transparent material.
Most probably Silk or Organza fabric.

You can find some examples of them on Etsy https://www.etsy.com/ca/listing/549549557/custom-color-organza-genie-leg-warmers

I do not believe they are historically accurate, or as easy to wear as Anime characters make it look.
More like something fantasy creators made to make Genies/Magical characters cuter/sexier.
A bit like super huge swords, weighting more than a car, that heroes can lift effortlessly with one hand.

They go for the look more than the realism.

Answer (score 1):

As per cosplay site, it's listed as [足カバー](http://www.cossuki.jp/goods.php?id=2726).

In short, it's more of a ["foot cover"](https://search.rakuten.co.jp/search/mall/%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC+%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD/), as opposed to something like loose/knee-high socks seen as a set with school uniforms.

I believe their purpose is partially for utility to cover the leg, but at the same time allow someone to wear more fashionable shoes or sandals. But then again I don't know what fashionable, maybe it's just for being a cute play on the magic school uniform motif.